# ECS clarify on resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm having trouble understanding the config definitions of a task.

I want to understand the resources. There are a few options (if we talk only about memory):

- `memory`
- `containerDefinitions.memory`
- `containerDefinitions.memoryReservation`

There are a few things I'm not sure about.

First of all, the docs say that when the hard limit is exceeded, the container will stop running. Isn't the goal of a container orchestration service to keep the service alive?

Root level `memory` must be greater than all containers `memory`. In theory I would imagine once there aren't enough containers deployed, new containers are created for the image. I wouldn't like to use more resources than I need, but if I reserve the `memory` on root level, first, I do reserve much more than needed, and second, if my application receives a huge load, the whole cluster will shut down if the memory limit is exceeded or what?

I want to implement a system that auto-scales, and I would imagine that this way I don't have to define resources allocated, it just uses the amount needed, and deploys/kills new containers if the load increases/decreases.

For me there are a lot of confusion around ECS, and Fargate, and how it works, how it scales, and the more I read about it, the more confusing it gets.

I would like to set the minimum amount of resources per container, at how much load to create a new container, and at how much load to kill one (because it's not needed anymore).

P.S. not experienced in devops in general, I used kubernetes at my company, and there are things I'm not clear about, just learning this ECS world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, the docs say that when the hard limit is exceeded, the container will stop running. Isn't the goal of a container orchestration service to keep the service alive?

I would say the goal of a container orchestration service is to deploy your containers, and restart them if they fail for some reason. A container orchestration service can't magically add RAM to a server as needed.

> I want to implement a system that auto-scales, and I would imagine that this way I don't have to define resources allocated, it just uses the amount needed, and deploys/kills new containers if the load increases/decreases.

No, you always have to define the amount of RAM and CPU that you want to reserve for each of your Fargate tasks. Amazon charges you by the amount of RAM and CPU you reserve for your Fargate tasks, regardless of what your application actually uses, because Amazon is having to allocate physical hardware resources to your ECS Fargate task to ensure that much RAM and CPU are always available to your task.

Amazon can't add extra RAM or CPU to a running Fargate task just because it suddenly needs more. There will be other processes, of other AWS customers, running on the same physical server, and there is no guarantee that extra RAM or CPU are available on that server when you need it. That is why you have to allocate/reserve all the CPU and RAM resources your task will need at the time it is deployed.

You can configure autoscaling to trigger on the amount of RAM your tasks are using, to start more instances of your task, thus spreading the load across more tasks which should hopefully reduce the amount of RAM being used by each of your individual tasks. You have to realize each of those new Fargate task instances created by autoscaling are spinning up on different physical servers, and each one is reserving a specific amount of RAM on the server they are on.

> I would like to set the minimum amount of resources per container, at how much load to create a new container, and at how much load to kill one (because it's not needed anymore).

You need to allocate the maximum amount of resources all the containers in your task will need, not the minimum. Because more physical resources can't be allocated to a single task at run time.

You would configure autoscaling with the target value, of for example 60% RAM usage, and it would automatically add more task instances if the average of the current instances exceeds 60%, and automatically start removing instances if the average of the current instances is well below 60%.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do the auto scaling on 60%? I ended up with 10+ browser tabs, but I'm lost in the noise. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-service-auto-scaling/ this is the closest I got, but it doesn't seem like this is what I need for what you've described at the end.

Comment: The article you linked is exactly what you need. It shows how to configure ECS Fargate autoscaling with a target CPU usage of 60%. If you would rather target 60% RAM usage you just need to change the CloudWatch metric being tracked.